# how to find windows services associated with particular user

Tags: windows, windows-services, psexec

Using the `sc` command, we can query, start, and stop windows services. For example:

```
sc query "windows service name"
```

Could someone tell me how we can find the windows services associated with particular user through the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Try below variation of tasklist

```
tasklist /v
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tasklist /SVC /FI "USERNAME ne NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
```

You need to change the last part to, for example, a domain user.